# RMI ClassCastException to remote interface

Tags: java, rmi, classcastexception

Hi i am having a problem with RMI.

I have this error when i run it.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to rmi.converter
```

This is the interface

converter.java

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public interface converter { 

double CelciusKelvin (double a) throws RemoteException;
double CelciusFahrenheit (double a) throws RemoteException;
double FahrenheitKelvin (double a) throws RemoteException;
double FahrenheitCelcius (double a) throws RemoteException;
double KelvinCelcius (double a) throws RemoteException;
double KelvinFahrenheit (double a) throws RemoteException;
double AtmosPascal (double a) throws RemoteException;
double AtmosPSI (double a) throws RemoteException;
double PascalAtmos  (double a) throws RemoteException;
double PascalPSI  (double a) throws RemoteException;
double PSIAtmos  (double a) throws RemoteException;
double PSIPascal  (double a) throws RemoteException;   
}
```

This is the remote method

converterImp.java

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;



public class converterImp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements converter {



public converterImp() throws RemoteException
{

}

   double convert;


@Override
public double CelciusKelvin(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert = a+273.15;
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double CelciusFahrenheit(double a) throws RemoteException {
   convert = (a*1.8)+32;
   return convert;
}

@Override
public double FahrenheitKelvin(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert = (a+459.67)*5/9;
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double FahrenheitCelcius(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert=(a-32)/(9/5);
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double KelvinCelcius(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert = a - 273.15;
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double KelvinFahrenheit(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert=(a-273.15)* 1.8 + 32.00;
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double AtmosPascal(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert = a*101325;
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double AtmosPSI(double a) throws RemoteException {
   convert = a*14.6959488;
   return convert;
}

@Override
public double PascalAtmos(double a) throws RemoteException {
   convert = a/101325; 
   return convert;
}

@Override
public double PascalPSI(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert=a*0.000145037;
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double PSIAtmos(double a) throws RemoteException {
    convert = a*0.0680459639;
    return convert;
}

@Override
public double PSIPascal(double a) throws RemoteException {
   convert =a*6894.75729;
   return convert; 
}

}
```

This is my GUI Client.

```
package projectrmiclient;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import rmi.converter;

public class ProjectRMIClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public ProjectRMIClient() {
    initComponents();
}
String num = "";
String str = "";



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton13 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton16 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton17 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton18 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton19 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton20 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton21 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton22 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton23 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextPane1.setEditable(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

    jButton1.setText("1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("3");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setText("4");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setText("5");
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton6.setText("6");
    jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton7.setText("7");
    jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton8.setText("8");
    jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton9.setText("9");
    jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton10.setText("0");
    jButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton11.setText("Cancel");
    jButton11.setToolTipText("");
    jButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Temperature");

    jButton12.setText("C~F");
    jButton12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton12ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton13.setText("F~C");

    jButton14.setText("K~C");

    jButton15.setText("C~K");

    jButton16.setText("F~K");

    jButton17.setText("K~F");

    jButton18.setText("A~PSI");

    jButton19.setText("PSI~A");

    jButton20.setText("Pas~A");

    jButton21.setText("A~Pas");

    jButton22.setText("PSI-Pas");
    jButton22.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton22ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton23.setText("Pas~A");

    jLabel2.setText("Pressure");

    jLabel3.setText("Result");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 205, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton11)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addGap(36, 36, 36)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addComponent(jButton5)
                        .addComponent(jButton6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton7)
                        .addComponent(jButton8)
                        .addComponent(jButton9))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton11)
                        .addComponent(jButton10))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton15)
                        .addComponent(jButton12))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton16)
                        .addComponent(jButton13))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton17)
                        .addComponent(jButton14))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton18)
                        .addComponent(jButton21))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButton22)
                        .addComponent(jButton19))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton20)
                        .addComponent(jButton23))))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);

}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    str = evt.getActionCommand();
    num = num + str;
    jTextPane1.setText(num);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    jTextPane1.setText("");
}                                         

private void jButton22ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     try {
        // fire to localhost port 1099
        Registry myRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);

        // search for myMessage service
        converter impl = (converter) myRegistry.lookup("PTConverter");

        if(!jTextPane1.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            double input = Double.parseDouble(jTextPane1.getText());
            // call server's method  
            double result=impl.CelciusFahrenheit(input);
            String answer = result + "Fahrenheit";
            jLabel4.setText(answer);

        }




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProjectRMIClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProjectRMIClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProjectRMIClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProjectRMIClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ProjectRMIClient().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton14;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton15;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton16;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton17;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton18;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton19;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton20;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton21;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton22;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton23;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I developed the GUI using GUI Builder on netbeans.
The problem is when i pressed jButton12. it will show the error as stated.

Comment: What package is the `converter` interface in?

Comment: @EJP it is in package converter along with converterImp

Comment: So where did the name `rmi.converter` come from?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have created a copy of your remote interface in a different package for the client. You can't do that. The remote interface has to be the same on both sides: **The Same**, and that does not include changing its package, or indeed any anything else.

Comment: In addition to the packaging, shouldn't the remote interface `converter` extends the `java.rmi.Remote` interface?

Comment: @STaefi Yes indeed, well spotted. I doubt that exporting would succeed if it didn't n reality.